# How to remove XCode3?

Tags: xcode4, xcode3to4

I have XCode4 installed in my Developer folder, and XCode3 installed in another folder called XCode3. I would like to completely remove XCode3. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don’t need Xcode 3 anymore, move XCode 3 to ‘/Developer-old’ then just run in your terminal:

```
sudo /Developer-old/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

This removes all Xcode3 files, freeing up about 5Gb of space.